# Grouping Data from a text file in C#

Tags: c#, file

I am currently working on a small project that returns text from 'txt' file based on criteria and then groups it before I export it to a database. In the text file I have:

c:\test\123

Other Lines...

c:\test\124

Problem: "description of error". (this error is for directory 124)

Problem: "description of error". (this error is for directory 124)

c:\test\125

...

I would like to group the 'problems' to their associated directory when importing them to the database. So far I have tried using 'foreach' to return the rows where the line contains/begins with directory or problem. Although this passes the value in order it is not clear for users to see which directory the problem belongs to. Ideally I am after:

**Directory**(column1)           **Problem**(column2)

c:\test\123        ||            Null

c:\test\124        ||            Problem: "description of Error".

c:\test\124        ||            Problem: "description of Error".

c:\test\125        ||            Null

Any help that you can give would be greatly appreciated. I have been racking my brains on this for the last week!

(current code)

```
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
        {
            String stringTest = line;

            if (stringTest.Contains(directory))
            {
                String test = stringTest;

                var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                csb.DataSource = host;
                csb.InitialCatalog = catalog;
                csb.UserID = user;
                csb.Password = pass;

                using (var sc = new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
                using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
                {
                    sc.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM table";
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (ID, Directory) values (NEWID(), @val)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL", test);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sc.Close();
                }
            }

            if (stringTest.Contains(problem))
            {
```

Same for problem....

Comment: So you are considering only the lines which start with "Problem"?

Comment: I am yes. There are other lines in the file but I am focussed on returning the Problem lines after each directory entry.

Comment: It would be useful to post the code you currently have, to save others time from suggesting things you have already tried and discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

Assuming that you have the following class to hold a result item:

```
public class ResultItem
{
    public string Directory { get; set; }
    public string Problem { get; set; }
}
```

You can do the following:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

string current_directory = null;

List<ResultItem> results = new List<ResultItem>();

//maintain the number of results added for the current directory
int problems_added_for_current_directory = 0;

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("c:\\test"))
    {
        //If we are changing to a new directory
        //And we didn't add any items for current directory
        //Add a null result item
        if (current_directory != null && problems_added_for_current_directory == 0)
        {
            results.Add(new ResultItem
            {
                Directory = current_directory,
                Problem = null
            });                            
        }

        current_directory = line;

        problems_added_for_current_directory = 0;
    }
    else if (line.StartsWith("Problem"))
    {
        results.Add(new ResultItem
        {
            Directory = current_directory,
            Problem = line
        });

        problems_added_for_current_directory++;
    }
}

//If we are done looping
//And we didn't add any items for current (last) directory
//Add a null result item
if (current_directory != null && problems_added_for_current_directory == 0)
{
    results.Add(new ResultItem
    {
        Directory = current_directory,
        Problem = null
    });
}
```

Comment: that is a gret answer and produces exactly what I need.